# What does ColorWriteChannels1,2,3 do?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

What is the difference between ColorWriteChannels and ColorWriteChannels1 etc. in BlendStates in Monogame (or XNA or FNA etc.)? I can't find anthing that answers my question in the online Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like ColorWriteChannels1, ColorWriteChannels2, etc... are used only when a pixel shader is writing to multiple RenderTargets simultaneously. If you're only rendering to a single buffer then you wouldn't need them.